# Global truncation error of backward Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

It's often found in books that the global truncation error of the forward Euler method applied to $\dot{y} (t) = f(t, y(t))$ is given by something like

$$ \frac{\exp(LT) -1}{L} \frac{Mh}{2},$$

with $L$ the Lipshitz constant of $f$, $h$ the step length and $M$ a bound on the second derivative of $y$. I was wondering: apart from solving the stability issue, does backward Euler method improve this exponential dependence on the Lipshitz constant?

Comment: How do you define the local truncation error? The expression should involve the second derivative of $y$.

Comment: Corrected, I confused local and global. I didn't put the bound on $y''$  it because I didn't care to be preise, in fact. I mean, what I am asking is basically what error bounds we know for backward Euler, if they are substantially different from the forward ones. As for the definition of error I am interested in, it's the norm of the difference at time $T$ of the real solution $y(T)$ and the point $y_{T/h}$you find with the method.

Comment: The error is not different between forward and backward Euler. It is really just that forward Euler has restrictions due to stability that backwards Euler does not have, for the price of iteratively solving an implicit equation per step.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695950/implicit-euler-local-error-issue/1696107#1696107, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572896/global-error-bound-for-implicit-euler, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790240/if-forward-euler-is-an-over-approximation-does-that-imply-that-backward-euler-is/3790429#3790429